# Is version.pm available in CPAN any longer?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to find the Perl Module `version.pm` to fix the error below I am receiving while trying to install module `CPAN-Meta-Requirements-2.133`. But I don't see `version.pm`, the only one I see is [Version.PM](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-2.10/lib/CPAN/Version.pm) which is obviously not the one Perl is looking for. Can anyone point to where I can get this version or how I can fix this dependency if version.pm is no longer available?

**Perl Version:**
v5.16.3

**OS:**
GNU/Linux 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64

**Error:**

```
Can't locate version.pm in @INC (@INC contains:    # Line breaks added
   /root/CPAN-Meta-Requirements-2.133/blib/lib     # for readability
   /root/CPAN-Meta-Requirements-2.133/blib/arch
   /usr/local/lib64/perl5
   /usr/local/share/perl5
   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/lib64/perl5
   /usr/share/perl5
   .) at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/CPAN-Meta-Requirements-2.133/blib/lib/CPAN/Meta/Requirements.pm line 48.
Compilation failed in require at t/accepts.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/accepts.t line 4.
t/accepts.t ............ Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so first: your link is to `CPAN/Version.pm`.  This is very different than `version.pm`.  Directory names and the path relative to Perl's include directory are very important to Perl, and putting a .pm file in the wrong location relative to the include path can break Perl pretty badly.

Second: because of that, *never install Perl modules manually*.  Use [cpanm](http://cpanmin.us) instead:

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus # Omit --sudo if your perl isn't installed as root
cpanm version
```

Third: the `version.pm` that you want is this one: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version.pod, in the JPEACOCK/version-0.9912 distribution.

Comment: If your instructions fail the OP somehow then `cpanminus` won't help you to diagnose them. It isn't a solution to anything except frustration, and you should recommend [***`CPAN`***](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-2.10/lib/CPAN.pm) instead, which is already installed and gives useful diagnostics

Comment: @Borodin: it's interesting you think that, because it hasn't been my experience at all.  I suppose if `CPAN` is already configured for the OP then it would work.  But my experience has been that any issue I have with `cpanm` can be solved by examining the log file it tells me to look at.

Comment: Thanks jcast.  Yes CPAN is not installed by default on this server.  I am on a new server so I was trying to install CPAN currently and these are the dependencies I have to install to use CPAN.  I will try that cpanmin.us and see if that works for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Or just `cpan version`. No need to go through all the trouble of installing `cpanm` first. Your whole configuration comment is nonsense. PERL_MM_OPT and PERL_MB_OPT are processed by EU::MM and M::B reguardless of whether the script was started by `cpan` or `cpanm`.

Comment: installing the cpan version is likely not the right thing; figuring out why the already installed perl doesn't have it and what distribution package(s) are missing is.

Answer (score 2):

*version* has come with Perl since Perl 5.10, so it's weird that you would have to install it.

```
$ corelist version
version was first released with perl v5.9.0
```

But [*version*](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?version) is also available on CPAN in its own [distribution](http://search.cpan.org/dist/version) in order to allow people to upgrade *version* without upgrading Perl.

So you may indeed install it as any other module.

```
cpan version
```

Comment: He's probably using a perl compiled and packaged by somebody else and "helpfully" trimmed down to the "bare essentials".  Also: note that he *doesn't have* `cpan`, since his perl is "barebones"!